# Is this the approved way to acess data adjacent to/packaged with a Python script?

Tags: python, resources, packaging

I have a Python script that needs some data that's stored in a file that will always be in the same location as the script. I have a `setup.py` for the script, and I want to make sure it's pip installable in a wide variety of environments, and can be turned into a standalone executable if necessary.

Currently the script runs with Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 or higher (though I don't have a test environment for 3.3 so I can't be sure about that).

I came up with this method to get the data. This script isn't part of a module directory with `__init__.py` or anything, it's just a standalone file that will work if just run with `python` directly, but also has an entry point defined in the `setup.py` file. It's all one file. Is this the correct way?

```
def fetch_wordlist():
    wordlist = 'wordlist.txt'
    try:
        import importlib.resources as res
        return res.read_binary(__file__, wordlist)
    except ImportError:
        pass
    try:
        import pkg_resources as resources
        req = resources.Requirement.parse('makepw')
        wordlist = resources.resource_filename(req, wordlist)
    except ImportError:
        import os.path
        wordlist = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), wordlist)
    with open(wordlist, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()
```

This seems ridiculously complex.  Also, it seems to rely on the package management system in ways I'm uncomfortable with. The script no longer works unless it's been pip-installed, and that also doesn't seem desirable.

Comment: What's wrong with using only the `os.path` based approach?

Comment: @Leon - It doesn't work if the thing has been stuffed into a `.zip` or someone has used py2exe on it or something. Python module files are not always actually files on the filesystem, particularly if they're packaged using setuptools or distutils.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Resources living on the filesystem

The standard way to read a file adjacent to your python script would be:

a) If you've got python>=3.4 I'd suggest you use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, like this:

```
from pathlib import Path


def fetch_wordlist(filename="wordlist.txt"):
    return (Path(__file__).parent / filename).read_text()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fetch_wordlist())
```

b) And if you're still using a python version <3.4 or you still want to use the good old [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module you should do something like this:

```
import os


def fetch_wordlist(filename="wordlist.txt"):
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)) as f:
        return f.read()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fetch_wordlist())
```

Also, I'd suggest you capture exceptions in the outer callers, the above methods are standard way to read files in python so you don't need wrap them in a function like `fetch_wordlist`, said otherwise, reading files in python is an "atomic" operation.

Now, it may happen that you've frozen your program using some freezer such as `cx_freeze`, `pyinstaller` or [similars](https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/)... in that case you'd need to detect that, here's a simple way to check it out:

a) using `os.path`:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    app_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
elif __file__:
    app_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

b) using `pathlib`:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    app_path = Path(sys.executable).parent
elif __file__:
    app_path = Path(__file__).parent
```

### Resources living inside a zip file

The above solutions would work if the code lives on the file system but it wouldn't work if the package is living inside a zip file, when that happens you could use either [importlib.resources](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) (new in version 3.7) or [pkg_resources](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) combo as you've already shown in the question (or you could wrap up in some helpers) or you could use a nice 3rd party library called `importlib_resources` that should work with the old&modern python versions:

- pypi: https://pypi.org/project/importlib_resources/
- documentation: https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Specifically for your particular problem I'd suggest you take a look to this https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#file-system-or-zip-file.

If you want to know what that library is doing behind the curtains because you're not willing to install any 3rd party library you can find the code for py2 [here](https://gitlab.com/python-devs/importlib_resources/blob/master/importlib_resources/_py2.py) and py3 [here](https://gitlab.com/python-devs/importlib_resources/blob/master/importlib_resources/_py3.py) in case you wanted to get the relevant bits for your particular problem

Comment: Also, I clarified things a bit in my question. I like `__file__`, but it doesn't work in all situations.

Comment: Ok, good you've clarified the question, now it makes more sense. And about pathlib, this module was introduced on version `3.4.`, I'll edit my answer to adjust it to the new question :)

Comment: @Omnifarious Edited my answer, hope that helps

Comment: @BPL I guess OP means that the resource file (`wordlist.txt`) is frozen too and is located *inside* the package rather than *near* it.

Comment: @Leon - Yes, that's exactly correct. I wasn't sure how to get at what I meant.

Comment: @Omnifarious Edited again, hope this time I've been able to understand your question completely :)

Comment: @BPL - Indeed, it seems to be a complete answer.  My general policy on bounties is to wait to award them until not long before it expires. I'll set myself an alarm. :-) Your answer basically seems to say that what I'm doing is sort of correct, but is organized poorly. :-)

Comment: To be honest with you, usually I always try to avoid using dependencies on my software if I'm able to control all the use-cases with minimalistic code but in this case, having a 3rd party lib such as `importlib_resources` which is giving you an uniform layer to handle both python2.x and python3.x looks to me like a smart choice. If I found myself in your situation I'd use that lib. About your general policy of bounties, I also do the same :) . That usually will make a thread richer in content. And when I judge who deserves the bounty I'll also consider the time a legit answer was given ;) Gl!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go out on a limb and make an assumption because it may drastically simplify your problem. The only way I can imagine that you can claim that this data is "stored in a file that will always be in the same location as the script" is because you created this data, once, and put it in a file in the source code directory. Even though this data is binary, have you considered making the data a literal byte-string in a python file, and then simply importing it as you would anything else?

Comment: I have. It's actually not binary, but to save space I bzip2 compressed it and stored it in a base64 string. It was kind of unwieldy, but it worked. I stored it in the same file as the rest of the source, but making it into a separate module would work better. I might do that as it gets around all of the stupidity and ugliness.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the fact that your method of reading a file is a bit unnecessarily complex. Unless you have got a really specific reason to use the `importlib` and `pkg_resources` modules, it's rather simple.

```
import os

def fetch_wordlist():
    if not os.path.exists('wordlist.txt'):
        raise FileNotFoundError

    with open('wordlist.txt', 'rb') as wordlist:
        return wordlist.read()
```

You haven't given much information regarding your script, so I cannot comment on why it doesn't work unless it's installed using `pip`. My best guess: your script is probably packed into a python package.

Comment: I tried to clarify a bit more. This script is currently pip installable, and I want to keep it that way. And if someone wants to stuff it into a zip file, or into py2exe or something, I want it to continue to work.

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense now. I would say BPL's solution would work quite well in that case.